# How can I encrypt/decrypt with only letters of the alphabet in ASCII table for Caesar Cipher program?

Tags: python, encryption

```
#Encryption and Decryption Program
offset_1 = ''
 # A = 1
 # B = 2
 # C = 3
 # D = 4
 # E = 5
 # F = 6
 # G = 7
 # H = 8
 # I = 9
 # J = 10
 # K = 11
 # L = 12
 # M = 13
 # N = 14
 # O = 15
 # P = 16
 # Q = 17
 # R = 18
 # S = 19
 # T = 20
 # U = 21
 # V = 22
 # W = 23
 # X = 24
 # Y = 25
 # Z = 26

#Encryption/Decryption Choice
choice = input("Please select encryption or decryption.")
if choice == "e" or choice == "E" or choice == "encrypt" or choice == "Encrypt":
    print ("Your choice is encryption.")

 elif choice == "d" or choice == "D" or choice == "decrypt" or choice == "Decrypt":
    print ("Your choice is decryption.")

# Offset Choice
offset_1 = input("Please select an offset.")
print ("Your offset is " + offset_1)

# Message Choice
message_1 = input("Please input your message")
print ("Your message is " + message_1)
# Code for encryption
for counter in range(len(message_1)):
    print (chr(ord(message_1[counter])+int(offset_1)))
# Code for decryption
for counter in range(len(message_1)):
    print (chr(ord(message_1[counter])-int(offset_1)))
```

As I am using ASCII table for this Caesar Cipher program, can someone perhaps explain how I can encrypt/decrypt using the letters of the alphabet only, without special characters such as £$%^.

I know that this program is incomplete, however I will readjust it once the fundamental of this purpose is completed.

This is for Python 3.0 and practising with Caesar Cipher.

Thanks.

Comment: Please search the site or using google for "*caesar cipher python*" and you'll get innumerable hits.

Comment: I would advise you index at 0. This makes a ring, and allows you to utilize modulo arithmetic and simplify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing you're missing is that the Caesar cypher *wraps*, so if you go past 'Z', you should wrap back to 'A'.  Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: Yep, either use the modulus operation of Python or check your bounds with an if statement.